# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, mongodb, express

Estoy realizando el despliegue de mi aplicacion en *render.com*, y estoy teniendo este problema, os comento:
Creo una aplicacion con Nodejs, Express, Mongodb y react, con sus paginas cliente y servidor diferenciados. En local funciona todo correctamente, pero cuando realizo el `npm run build` en *render.com* (el servidor en el que lo estoy desplegando), me ocurre este error al intentar logearme desde el frontend:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

La cosa es que el error viene de el javascript que se genera al hacer el build, porque como digo, en local funciona todo correctamente.
He mirado y remirado las variables de entorno y parecen estar correctas (con los datos que deben llevar) y creo tener el CORS bien configurado.

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: FRONTEND_URL,
  credentials: true
}))
```

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano, cualquier ayuda es de utilidad!!

PD: Tengo la aplicacion subida a github, aqui os dejo el link: https://github.com/RoberVF/MERN_STACK_AUTH/tree/master

Comment: Será que tienes mal el valor de FRONTEND_URL? ensaya con `origin:true` solo para probar que funcione, y si funciona es porque el valor de esa variable está mal